# I want to distinguish the link of d3.js force graph by the thickness

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, force-layout

I want to distinguish the link by the thickness.

I have the data.

The variable "`value`" means "`thickness`".

The range of "value" is 0~1.

```
    {"nodes":[{"name":"A", "group":1},
              {"name":"B", "group":1},
              {"name":"C", "group":1},
              {"name":"D", "group":1},
              {"name":"E", "group":1}],
     "links":[{"source":0,"target":1,"value":0.9},
              {"source":0,"target":2,"value":0.8},
              {"source":0,"target":3,"value":0.7},
              {"source":1,"target":2,"value":0.7},
              {"source":2,"target":4,"value":0.2},
              {"source":0,"target":4,"value":0.5}]}
```

And my d3.js graph code is

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <body><script src="../d3-master/d3.min.js"></script>
    <head><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../D3css/D3css.css"></head>

    <script>

    var width = 960,
        height = 500

    var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
        .attr("width", width)
        .attr("height", height);

    var force = d3.layout.force()
        .gravity(.05)
        .distance(100)
        .charge(-100)
        .size([width, height]);

    d3.json("../data/cor_test.json", function(error, json) {

      force
        .nodes(json.nodes)
        .links(json.links)
        .start();

      var link = svg.selectAll(".link")
          .data(json.links)
        .enter().append("line")
          .attr("class", "link");

      var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
          .data(json.nodes)
        .enter().append("g")
          .attr("class", "node")
          .call(force.drag);

      node.append("circle")
          .attr("r", 5);

      node.append("text")
          .attr("dx", 12)
          .attr("dy", ".35em")
          .text(function(d) { return d.name });

      force.on("tick", function() {
        link.attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
            .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
            .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
            .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });

        node.attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; });
      });
    });

    </script>
```

I changed the code like this.

but it doesn't work.

```
      var link = svg.selectAll(".link")
          .data(json.links)
        .enter().append("line")
          .attr("class", "link")
          .attr("stroke-width", function(d) { return d.value; });
```

More simply change : `.attr("stroke-width", "5px");` doesn't work too.

The link didn't show.

What should I do?

Comment: Could you turn your example into a jsfiddle to allow live experimenting? Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to specify the `'stroke'` attribute first, because:

> The default value for the stroke attribute is **none** which means that the outline is never drawn.

See the [documentation for `stroke`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/stroke). Below is an example of how it might be done:

```
selection
    .attr('stroke', 'red')
    .attr('stroke-width', 5);
```

Here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ju89p/) demonstrating how it works.

Answer (score 1):

I believe @Oleg 's answer is complete and right on, however, I just want to bring to your attention an example that makes extensive use of link thicknesses, and other related svg attributes:

[2013 Budget Visualization](http://www.brightpointinc.com/interactive/budget/index.html?source=d3js)

[image]

Relevant code is here:

```
        // Enter any new links at the parent's previous position.
    link.enter().insert("svg:path", "g")
            .attr("class", "link")
            .attr("d", function(d) {
                if (Number(d.target[spendField]) > 0) {
                    var o = {x: source.x0, y: source.y0};
                    return diagonal({source: o, target: o});
                }
                else {
                    null;
                }
            })
            .style("stroke",function (d,i) {
                if (d.source.depth==0) {
                    rootCounter++;
                    return (d.source.children[rootCounter-1].linkColor);
                }
                else {
                    return (d.source) ? d.source.linkColor : d.linkColor;
                }
            })
            .style("stroke-width", function (d,i) {

                if (d.source.depth==0) {
                    var ret = level1Radius(d.target[spendField]) * 2;
                    return (isNaN(ret) ? 4 : ret);
                }
                else if (d.source.depth==1) {
                    var ret = level2Radius(d.target[spendField]) * 2;
                    return (isNaN(ret) ? 4 : ret);
                }
                else if (d.source.depth==2) {
                    var ret = level3Radius(d.target[spendField]) * 2;
                    return (isNaN(ret) ? 4 : ret);
                }
                else if (d.source.depth==3) {
                    var ret = level4Radius(d.target[spendField]) * 2;
                    return (isNaN(ret) ? 4 : ret);
                }
             })
            .style("stroke-opacity", function(d){
                var ret = ((d.source.depth+1)/4.5)
                if (d.target[spendField] <= 0) ret=.1;
                return ret;
            })
            .style("stroke-linecap","round")
            .transition()
            .duration(duration);
      //      .attr("d", diagonal);


    // Transition links to their new position.
     var linkUpdate = link.transition()
            .duration(duration)
            .attr("d", diagonal);

     linkUpdate
             .style("stroke-width", function (d,i) {
                 if (d.source.depth==0) {
                     var ret = level1Radius(Number(d.target[spendField])) * 2;
                     return (isNaN(ret) ? 4 : ret);
                 }
                 else if (d.source.depth==1) {
                     var ret = level2Radius(Number(d.target[spendField])) * 2;
                     return (isNaN(ret) ? 4 : ret);
                 }
                 else if (d.source.depth==2) {
                     var ret = level3Radius(Number(d.target[spendField])) * 2;
                     return (isNaN(ret) ? 4 : ret);
                 }
                 else if (d.source.depth==3) {
                     var ret = level4Radius(Number(d.target[spendField])) * 2;
                     return (isNaN(ret) ? 4 : ret);
                 }
            })
         //    .style("stroke-dasharray", function(d) {
         //       var ret=(d.target[spendField] > 0) ? "" : "5,8";
         //       return ret;
         //    })
             .style("stroke-opacity", function(d){
                 var ret = ((d.source.depth+1)/4.5)
                 if (d.target[spendField] <= 0) ret=.1;
                 return ret;
             })


    // Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
    link.exit().transition()
            .duration(duration)
            .attr("d", diagonal)
            .remove();
```

Besides usage of `stroke`, `stroke-width`, you can notice usage of `stroke-opacity`, `stroke-linecap`, and general enter/update/exit pattern.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your advices, Oleg and VividD! I solved my problem. The cause was that I defined 'stroke' and 'stroke-width' option in my css file. so I removed it and added code .attr("stroke", "gray") .attr("stroke-width", function(d) { return d.value; })

Answer (score 1):

I think it was more to do with `style("stroke.width", 5)` rather than `attr("stroke.width", 5)` but I'm not sure, I'm new to d3.